# How to debug QML with a CMake project

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, cmake, qml

I have set the flag -DQT_QML_DEBUG and checked "Enable QML" in "Build and run > Run > Debugger settings" (my translation) but still I cant step with the debugger. The instruction pointer is simply not shown the text view does not follow the instructoin pointer. Addtitionally I get this warnings on start:

```
Warning: "QML Debugger: Invalid argument 'services:DebugMessages' detected. Ignoring the same."
Warning: "QML Debugger: Invalid argument 'QmlDebugger' detected. Ignoring the same."
Warning: "QML Debugger: Invalid argument 'V8Debugger' detected. Ignoring the same."
Warning: "QML Debugger: Invalid argument 'QmlInspector' detected. Ignoring the same."
QML Debugger: Waiting for connection on port 39750...
```

Edit: Environtment is archlinux, hence latest versions.

Comment: For anyone who lands here in 2021, there is bug in QTCreator (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-23541) which is "resolved", but still ocured for me in 4.14.0. For me worked to do the following: add `QT_QML_DEBUG` define and uncheck "Enable QML" toggle, then recompile all, then enable "Enable QML", then again recompile all.

Answer (score 5):

Compiling qml files needs to be disabled for debugging.

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5QuickCompiler QUIET)
IF(Qt5QuickCompiler_FOUND AND NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug AND NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES RelWithDebInfo)
  QTQUICK_COMPILER_ADD_RESOURCES(RESOURCES qml.qrc)
ELSE()
  SET(RESOURCES qml.qrc)
ENDIF()

ADD_EXECUTABLE(my_target_name
  ...
  ${RESOURCES}
)
```

And the target needs to be built with `QT_QML_DEBUG`

```
TARGET_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS(my_target_name
  PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
```

This should work without playing with `QQmlDebuggingEnabler`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to your first two steps add

```
#include <QQmlDebuggingEnabler>

...

QQmlDebuggingEnabler enabler;
```

to your project's main.cpp.

That helped me, although I haven't seen your exact warning messages.

Comment: It didn't work for me, with Qt 5.1... Also, if I understood correctly, an instance of that type is already created in qqmldebug.h with `printWarning` param true.

Comment: This helped me with Qt 5.9 and CMake based project with QQuickWidget inside

Answer (score 1):

From Projects > Run > Debugger Settings
Deselect and Reselect Enable C++ and Enable QML

This worked for me on manjaro